# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'patroon' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I'll start by a simplified explanation of what my code (function) has to do:

I get a file with words in it that I have to code to morse code, so I have another file where each character has a morse code. My problem occurs when I want to put each word in a dictionary as a key with as value that morse code.

to get the pattern of the code and assign it to that word in my dictionary I use another function but it says 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'patroon' referenced before assignment'
while 'patroon' is actually my other function:

```
def patroon(woord, morse_dict, complement = False, spiegel = False):
    patroon_str = ''
    for letter in woord:
        patroon_str += morse_dict[letter.upper()]
    i=0

    if complement==True:
        patroon_list = list(patroon_str)
        for char in patroon_str:
            if char == '.':
                patroon_list[i]='-'
            elif char == '-': patroon_list[i]='.'
            i+=1
        patroon_str = ''.join(patroon_list)
    if spiegel == True:
        patroon_str = patroon_str[::-1]
    return patroon_str
```

and here is the function in which it is called:

```
def groepen(woordenloc, morseloc):
    morse_dict = morsecodes(morseloc)
    woordpatroon_dict = {}
    woorden = open(woordenloc, 'r')

    for woord in woorden:
        ***woordpatroon_dict[woord] = patroon(woord, morse_dict)***
    patroonwoorden_dict = {}
    for woord, patroon in woordpatroon_dict.items():
        if patroon in patroonwoorden_dict:
            patroonwoorden_dict[patroon].add(woord)
        else:
            patroonwoorden_dict[patroon] = {woord}
    return patroonwoorden_dict
```

where the stars are is where the error occurs
 I'm new to python so I don't really know if this would be enough information.

this is my full code:

```
def morsecodes(locatie):
    morse_file = open(locatie, 'r')
    morse_dict = {}
    for line_str in morse_file:
        new_l = line_str.split()
        if new_l[0].isalpha:
            morse_dict[new_l[0].upper()] = new_l[1]
        else: morse_dict[new_l[0]] = new_l[1]
    return morse_dict

def patroon(woord, morse_dict, complement = False, spiegel = False):
    patroon_str = ''
    for letter in woord:
        patroon_str += morse_dict[letter.upper()]
    i=0

    if complement==True:
        patroon_list = list(patroon_str)
        for char in patroon_str:
            if char == '.':
                patroon_list[i]='-'
            elif char == '-': patroon_list[i]='.'
            i+=1
        patroon_str = ''.join(patroon_list)
    if spiegel == True:
        patroon_str = patroon_str[::-1]
    return patroon_str

def isomorse(woord1, woord2, morse_dict, complement = False, spiegel = False):
    patroon1 = patroon(woord1, morse_dict)
    patroon2 = patroon(woord2, morse_dict, complement, spiegel)
    if patroon1 == patroon2: return True
    else: return False

def groepen(woordenloc, morseloc):
    morse_dict = morsecodes(morseloc)
    woordpatroon_dict = {}
    woorden = open(woordenloc, 'r')

    for woord in woorden:
        woordpatroon_dict[woord] = patroon(woord, morse_dict)
    patroonwoorden_dict = {}
    for woord, patroon in woordpatroon_dict.items():
        if patroon in patroonwoorden_dict:
            patroonwoorden_dict[patroon].add(woord)
        else:
            patroonwoorden_dict[patroon] = {woord}
    return patroonwoorden_dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake, apparently python isn't (yet) smart enough to keep the name patroon as function and the 'patroon' as variable in my for loop separately (which I later use in the same function  'groepen')